# How to make my multi-object tracker more efficient？

Tags: python, opencv, data-structures, computer-vision

Since the `MultiTracker` in `OpenCV` cannot handle trackers individually, I decided to build my own.

It would be something like this with more attributes:

```
MT = {ID_num:{'dist':[], 'speed':[], 'bbox'=[], 'tracker'=<tracker object>}}
```

but obviously, it's not efficient at all. Because if I want to use distance info, I need something like `MT[1]['dist']`.

I know it seems it fits the characteristics of `Class` because they all have the same attributes. However, I need to call by their `ID_num` (keys). So I don't know how to construct this container as a multi-object tracker.

I also try use separate dictionaries for each attributes (with shared `ID_num`):

```
dist = {ID_num:[]}
speed = {ID_num:[]}
...
```

But it's ugly and makes it difficult to make adjustments. It would the perfect if you could offer some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found one that seems to work:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)

Dict = {ID_num: Foo(atrr1=[1,1], attr2=[2,2]),  ...}
```

In this way, I bind the ID with their attributes together instead of naming directly. The usage will be like:

```
val = MultiTracker[ID].attr1
```

Of course, it's slower (almost 2 times) than separately defining dictionaries, I tested using the following code. Results are `18.5FPS` and `9.2FPS` respectively for 10k repetition, which is acceptable:

```
attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4={},{},{},{}
MT = {}
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10):
        attr1[j],attr2[j],attr3[j],attr4[j] = [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]
print("first: %.3f FPS" % (1/(time.time()-t1)))

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10):
        MT[j] = Foo(attr1=[1,1,1,1], attr2=[1,1,1,1], attr3=[1,1,1,1], attr4=[1,1,1,1])
print("second: %.3f FPS" % (1/(time.time()-t1)))
```

Please instruct me if this method is bad though... I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [multi object tracker](https://github.com/abewley/sort) might handle your case. It can track multiple objects in real-time and is easy to implement. You would pass in the bboxes and scores in the form `[[x1,y1,x2,y2,score],[x1,y1,x2,y2,score],...]` and this returns the same boxes but with a tracking_id: `[[x1,y1,x2,y2,tracking_id],[x1,y1,x2,y2,tracking_id],...]`.

Here is the example from the git repo:

```
from sort import *

#create instance of SORT
mot_tracker = Sort() 

# get detections
...

# update SORT
track_bbs_ids = mot_tracker.update(detections)

# track_bbs_ids is a np array where each row contains a valid bounding box and track_id (last column)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To my understanding, SORT requires detection AND prediction to track. The overall speed is dragged down by detection. I was trying to only initialize trackers for each 5 frame by detection, skipping 4 frames of detection. After my experiments, I found trackers can work fine, but data assotiation was bad(I only used IoU matcher)...